# Understanding Go's exec.Output() function

Tags: go

I was reading the source code for the `Output()` method of the `Cmd` type in Go's `exec` module (https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output):

```
// Output runs the command and returns its standard output.
// Any returned error will usually be of type *ExitError.
// If c.Stderr was nil, Output populates ExitError.Stderr.
func (c *Cmd) Output() ([]byte, error) {
    if c.Stdout != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("exec: Stdout already set")
    }
    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    c.Stdout = &stdout

    captureErr := c.Stderr == nil
    if captureErr {
        c.Stderr = &prefixSuffixSaver{N: 32 << 10}
    }

    err := c.Run()
    if err != nil && captureErr {
        if ee, ok := err.(*ExitError); ok {
            ee.Stderr = c.Stderr.(*prefixSuffixSaver).Bytes()
        }
    }
    return stdout.Bytes(), err
}
```

I'm struggling a bit to understand this part:

```
    if ee, ok := err.(*ExitError); ok {
        ee.Stderr = c.Stderr.(*prefixSuffixSaver).Bytes()
    }
```

As I understand it, the `ee` pointer will no longer be in scope at the end of the `if` block, and since the body of the `if` block is just setting the `Stderr` field of this instance, the only way this could be useful is through a side effect (like actually writing the prettified error). I don't immediately grasp how this is happening, though.

What does this bit of code do, essentially?

Comment: `ee` variable will be out of scope, but it points to the same `err` value in memory. The code simply type-asserts, ensures the same value implements some other interface as well. In some way it's similar to https://play.golang.org/p/di4tOd4d3PK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ee, ok := err.(*ExitError); ok {
```

If `err` is of type `*ExitError`, then `ee` will be a pointer to the ExitError stored in `err`. So, even though `ee` will go out of scope, the `*ExitError` will still be there, pointed to by `err`, and any changes made to it will stick.